# Java's Enum.valueOf() problem

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to derive an enum value from a String, like:

```
Level level = Enum.valueOf(Level.class, "WARNING");
```

But all I get is compiler warnings like:

```
Test.java:8: <T>valueOf(java.lang.Class<T>,java.lang.String) in java.lang.Enum cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class<java.util.logging.Level>,java.lang.String)
```

I know in JDK versions prior to 1.5 this:

```
Level level = Level.valueOf("WARNING");
```

would work, but I'm using JDK 1.6. Could anyone provide a working example for this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`java.util.logging.Level`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) simply isn't an enum. Did you actually *mean* that `Level` class, or a different one?

The second snippet you posted wouldn't work either, but if you're *really* talking about the normal `Level` class, you can use:

```
Level level = Level.parse("WARNING");
```

Comment: Damn, I've been assuming java.util.logging.Level is an enum all the time. No wonder why valueOf() failed all the time.

Answer (score 0):

`Level.WARNING`, as well as `Level.INFO` and other Loggin levels are no ENUM's.

They're `static final` variables in the `Level.java` class.